# Proyecto GUI alumnosNotas java

Tags: java, java-swing

soy nuevo en el foro. Me lo recomendaron para temas de programación. Estoy desarrollando un pequeño proyecto con una GUI hecha con swing la cual es capaz de asignar un array de String a un objeto alumno y un array de doubles al mismo objeto.

Cuando se ejecuta la ventana, hay un botón de mostrar notas, que instancia un JPanel y debería de crear los JLabel y JTextField automáticamente, dependiendo de las asignaturas y notas que tenga cada alumno, pero lo único que consigo es que me devuelva la referencia a donde está apuntando mi objeto, o almenos eso creo. adjunto código a ver si me podéis echar una mano. Gracias de ante mano.

Clase ventana:

```
ublic void ponComponentes(Contenedor contenedor){
    for(int i=0; i<contenedor.getSize(); i++){
        JLabel lbAsignatura = new JLabel();
        lbAsignatura.setBounds(100, 150, 250, 20);
        lbAsignatura.setLocation(i*135, 50);
        lbAsignatura.setText(String.valueOf(contenedor.getAlumnos().get(indice).getNotas().get(indice).getAsignaturas()[i]));

        JTextField tfNotas = new JTextField();
        jpPanelNotas.add(tfNotas);
        tfNotas.setBounds(200, 100, 40, 20);
        tfNotas.setLocation(i*100, 110);
        tfNotas.setText(String.valueOf(contenedor.getAlumnos().get(indice).getNotas().get(indice).getNotas()[i]));

        jpPanelNotas.add(lbAsignatura);
        jpPanelNotas.add(tfNotas);
    }
}
```

[image: Esa es la ejecución del software y mi error]

Muchas gracias de antemano. He puesto todo el código susceptible de tener algún error

Comment: Puedes usar https://pastebin.com/ o alguna otra plataforma de código para pegar todo el código, por lo que veo es extenso.

Comment: Por lo que veo en el ciclo **for** del método ponComponentes() estás creando las etiquetas y colocándolo en un lugar por medio de coordenadas. pero se están encimando una sobre otra. Cuando crea la nueva etiqueta la encima sobre la primera que había creado.

Comment: Varias cosas... Una pared de codigo no ayuda a descubrir cual es el problema.. tu problema esta en la vista.. definitivamente deberias poder acotar el problema a eso. es muy dificil leer y seguir todo asi. y @Reynald0 en realidad no se recomienda pegar el codigo afuera del sitio, se recomiendo hacer un [mcve]. El codigo se puede perder y la pregunta quedar invalida

Comment: Se que puede resultar un poco ambigua la pregunta y tanto código, he puesto todo el código referente a las distintas instancias que estoy usando. Creo que realmente el problema lo tengo en el método de ponComponentes(), pero no lo tengo claro. Gracias por responder @Reynald0

Comment: @Reynald0 tenías razón con respecto a los componentes, parece que estaban unos encima de otros, ya he arreglado el setLocation, pero sigo teniendo el problema de que me está sacando nada más que la referencia en el contenido de los TextField y los label y no se porqué. Tenía dos instancias en main de una misma cosa, ya lo he solucionado también

Comment: Efectivamente, era error en el ponComponentes() ya he conseguido poner los Label y los TextField, pero se me sale del array. Pongo en la descripción de mi problema el nuevo código de ponComponentes()

Comment: Lo que mandes a llamar al panel imprimelo en consola también. Pero en consola lo que vas a imprimir en vez del valor, será el tipo de dato. Ya con eso deberías poder tener una pista de lo que sucede.